# When a wizard performs the clone spell on someone else, who pays the downtime days?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, dnd-adventurers-league

When a wizard performs the clone spell on someone else, who pays the required 120 downtime days?

The latest Adventurers League FAQ [(7.1)](https://rpg.rem.uz/Dungeons%20%26%20Dragons/D%26D%205th%20Edition/Adventure%20League/DDAL%20-%20FAQ%20v7.1.pdf) states:

> A clone isn’t mature (and therefore
>   provides no benefit) until the recipient spends a
>   total of 120 downtime days after casting it.

This makes no sense seeing as I would receive it but not cast it.

Answer (score 10):

## The person the spell was cast on pays the Downtime

The phrasing of the answer in the AL FAQ makes this very clear

> [...] until the *recipient* spends a total of 120 downtime days [...]

Let me clarify the phrasing a little bit. You seem to be reading this as if this FAQ answer was directed to everyone. But, in fact, the answer is written as if speaking to a spellcaster who is capable of casting Clone.

To rephrase in a way that is less succinct, but more clear...this is essentially what they are saying:

> "If you cast the clone spell on someone (yourself or another), then the clone is not mature until the person the spell was cast on spends a total of 120 downtime days after you cast the spell on that individual."

To rephrase it for you, as someone on whom the spell is cast...

> "If someone else casts the Clone spell on you, then the clone is not mature until you have spent a total of 120 downtime days after they cast the spell."

Your confusion simply stems from who the subject of the answer was.